# How to use debugger keyword in firefox dev tools?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Statement 'debugger' did not breaks execution of javascript code in latest firefox (29, 30, 31, 32) developer tools. How to stop execution from code like statement 'debugger;' do in chrome or in firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new firefox (35+) debugger keyword is work.

Comment: You must have opened DevTools in JS page while debugger keyword is executed;